# Drop down values are overlapping in IOS - React Native, Expo

Tags: ios, expo, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to React Native,
I am creating react native application using expo client.
I have used **Picker** from **@react-native-community/picker**,
In IOS platform the picker values are Overlapping (below image).

[image]

here my code:

```
import { Picker } from "@react-native-community/picker";
export default function PropertyInfo() {
  const [usaStates, setUsaStates] = useState(usStates);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
       <View style={styles.container}>
           <View style={styles.picker}>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedState}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedState(itemValue)}
                    mode="dropdown"
                    style={styles.pickerItem}
                    itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
                  >
                    {usaStates.map((item) => {
                      return (
                        <Picker.Item
                          style={styles.pickerItem}
                          label={item.name}
                          value={item.abbreviation}
                          key={item.abbreviation}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
                  </Picker>
                </View>
           </View>
        </SafeAreaView>

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 safeAreaContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
picker: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: "#DFE1E4",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: "#394049",
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 16,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
pickerItem: {
    color: "#394049",
    letterSpacing: 0.001,
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontFamily: "OpenSans_400",
    fontSize: 14,
  },
})
```

my package.json:

```
@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1
```

But I need like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS `Picker` is not intended to be used like this. See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers . It's designed to be used either in a modal, or in a bottom sheet.
So you may use another library to achieve this, e.g. https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/menu.html

Answer (score 1):

This is Native IOS picker behavior so if you want to use same picker as Android you can use NativeBase/Picker
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref

If you install native base and import picker from Nativebase instead of React-native-community you don't have change your Picker code inside PropertyInfo function

```
yarn add native-base
import {Picker} from 'native-base'
```